# Re-ordering elements for smaller widths using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following basic nav bar, that when on smaller devices uses a hamburger menu. However, I'm hoping to improve the experience for when on mobile:

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active');
});

document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((link) =>
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburger.classList.remove('active');
    navMenu.classList.remove('active');
  })
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: grey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 112px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

.nav-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-icon:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.nav-branding {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: 0.7 ease;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 100px;
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="nav-branding">Site</a>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">What</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Where</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">When</a>
      </li>
    
    </ul>

    <!-- Icons -->
    <ul class="nav-icons">
      <li class="nav-icon"><img src="../../assets/search.svg" alt="search" width="24" height="24"></li>
      <li class="nav-icon"><img src="../../assets/account.svg" alt="account" width="24" height="24"></li>
      <li class="nav-icon"><img src="../../assets/cart.svg" alt="cart" width="24" height="24"></li>   
    </ul>

    <div class="hamburger">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

However, when on devices less than 768px, the elements from left to right should be

Burger menu -> Branding -> Icons

What is best practise for this & can anyone recommend a starting place?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered I could use the `order` property like so:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-branding {
    order: 1;
  }

  .nav-icons {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```